# SSRS Subscrption to place the report in a shared location using SQL Job

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

I need to set up a SQL job which will run the SSRS report and place the result in a shared drive on every second sunday of client calander. The Job can run every day but the report should be placed on second sunday. The report name should be appended with datetime stamp. We can use stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the requirements, this is something that can be easily accomplished with a power-shell script. For example, you can create a power-shell script which would run the SSRS report, store it in a shared location. And you can schedule this to run either everyday or schedule it to run only on every second Sunday.

As for the report appending with the datestamp time. You can add the date as an optional parameter and set the report to accept this parameter where it will append it to the report otherwise use GETDATE().

Answer (score 0):

the thing with the timestamp in the report file name won't be possible using standard ssrs subscriptions. but you can easily move/rename the file using a script, that should not take too long.
setting up ssrs subscriptions is really well documented on msdn. just google it. renaming files in script has also been done before.
if you want to avoid the script, use data driven subscriptions (enterprise feature) or google for busyreports on codeplex.